# windows profile got corrupted; a few patches?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, tabs, profile

We had a power outage while I was asleep, and I left my PC opened since I wasn't done working. By the time I woke up, my PC had booted up on its own but my profile was already seemingly corrupted:

[image]

I have tried a number of things to get my windows profile back, but nothing seems to work. Right now my biggest issues are my task bar buttons, as well as all 100+ tabs I had opened for research on chrome. It took me weeks to find all of those, but I can't access them.

My questions:

- Is there a way to copy my taskbar between profiles?
- Is there a file somewhere that chrome saves for all of
  the tabs it has opened?
- How can I get my profile back?
- Can I somehow extend software installation across to "all users" instead of just that one profile? if not, how would I copy these credentials(?) to the new profile?

If I could fix these issues, at least, I don't entirely mind losing that profile, but if I could get my profile back, even better.

Comment: This may help with respect to Chrome tabs if you can find then in the old profile.  .....  https://www.foxtonforensics.com/browser-history-examiner/chrome-history-location#:~:text=Chrome%20Session%20Data%20is%20stored,%27%20and%20%27Tabs%27%20files.

Comment: “Is there a way to copy my taskbar between profiles?” - No